# What could "amphorisage" mean?

Tags: vocabulaire

I encountered this while reading *Astérix*. The exchange goes as follows:

(Astérix and Obélix are walking down a newly-constructed Roman road out of Lutèce)

> Astérix: Quelle circulation !
>
> Obélix: Les jours de beau temps, il doit y avoir des amphorisages !

This word doesn't come up in any dictionaries nor in google image search, so I assume it's some sort of joke or play on words. What might it mean?

Comment: These Asterix questions are the best thing on this site. I'm laughing just reading the title

Comment: I'm glad you're enjoying them! I wish I could get all the wordplay as intuitively as native speakers do. I imagine there's a ton that I'm not even noticing.

Comment: Keep 'em coming! And don't worry, I until I was like 12-14 I had to my parents about things I didn't understand ^^ And there are probably other puns you're missing because they're hard to notice if you don't know what they're referring to, so don't hesitate to re-read them in a few years if you can ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a *jeu de mots* that won't be in any dictionary: in French, we have *embouteillage*, meaning a *traffic jam*, but containing the word *bouteille*. In Antiquity, *bouteilles* were *amphores*, so they re-used the construction for *embouteillage* to make *amphore* + *-age* = *amphorisage*.

The word does not really exist in French, it's just made up here. Nobody will understand what you say if you go around talking about *amphorisage* for traffic jams - well except maybe you could pass for somebody who has read Astérix, if people recognize the reference.

Be on the lookout for *jeux de mots* in Astérix, it has quite a few (*chaque été les Ibères deviennent plus rudes* is one of my favorites).